# Putting chemfig reactions in a circle

Tags: chemistry

A while back, I had a teacher that gave us organic chemistry reaction summaries e.g. suppose the topic was benzene, the summary looked like this:

[image]

I was wondering if this would be possible to replicate in LaTeX. I've started looking into chemfig, but is there any convenient way to make a "circle" of reaction like this? i.e. with automatic even spacing, putting reaction conditions on the arrows etc,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with alignment of the centers of the rings

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{arrow head=-latex, arrow coeff=2}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{**6(------)}
\arrow(cr--){->[*{0}up][*{0}down]}[30]\chemfig{**6((-[6,3,,,draw=none])----(-S(=[0]O)(=[4]O)-[2]OH)-(-[2,3,,,draw=none])-)}
\arrow(@cr--)[90]\chemfig{**6(----(-NO_2)--)}
\arrow(@cr--)[150]\chemfig{**6((-[6,2,,,draw=none])----(-Br)-(-[2,2,,,draw=none])-)}
\arrow(@cr--)[210]\chemfig{**6((-[6,2,,,draw=none])----(-CH_3)-(-[2,2,,,draw=none])-)}
\arrow(@cr--)[270]\chemfig{**6((-[4,3,,,draw=none])--(-[0,3,,,draw=none])-(-C(=[2]O)-[:330]CH_3)---)}
\arrow(@cr--)[330]\chemfig{*6(------)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

the subtitles are for you to put.

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{**6(@{a}-@{b}-@{c}-@{d}-@{e}-@{f}-)}
%
\arrow(@{a}--){->}[210,2]\chemfig{**6(----(-CH_3)--)}
\arrow(@{b}--){->}[270,2]\chemfig{**6(---(-C(=[2]O)-[:330]CH_3)---)}
\arrow(@{c}--){->}[330,2]\chemfig{*6(------)}
\arrow(@{d}--){->[*{0}up][*{0}down]}[30,2]\chemfig{**6(----(-S(=[0]O)(=[4]O)-[2]OH)--)}
\arrow(@{e}--){->}[90,2]\chemfig{**6(----(-NO_2)--)}
\arrow(@{f}--){->}[150,2]\chemfig{**6(----(-Br)--)}
%
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]